# angular.min.js not linking to view in mean stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I have the angular.min.js library installed on ubuntu 14.04 under /opt/mean/public/lib/angular/angular.min.js, and in a view made in accordance with a tutorial from lynda I have the following view:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular Demo</title>
        <script src="/opt/mean/public/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        <h2>Welcome {{name}}</h2>
    </body>
 </html>
```

The contents of the h2 tag should be dynamically updating as text is entered but it is not. Furthermore on the console I get a 404 error for the angular.min.js file.
The MEAN stack is the premade one found on digitalocean, if that matters.

Comment: You cannot  use a system path such as /opt/.... in a web application

Answer (score 1):

try using the path

```
/lib/angular/angular.min.js
```

instead of

```
/opt/mean/public/lib/angular/angular.min.js
```

Comment: It's giving a 304 result now, instead of a 404 result, but it still isn't updating. Do you see any other bugs in the body of it?

Comment: 304 is not an error!! 304 means Not Modified which means that the angular.min.js resource is already loaded in the browser cache

Comment: Ok, it works in firefox but not in chrome for whatever reason. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. Thank you very much!

Comment: I've added what is shown in the question, and the Lynda tutorial I'm using shows only that and has it updating.